# How to add more row numbers to linear regression charts

Tags: r, plot, linear-regression

I wonder how can I add more row numbers to points that are ploted on the linear regression residuals charts.Is there a way to add points number to the top 5% precents for example? or can I use a graphical position to mark specific rows? 
I added a toy data frame and made a model (how can I display rows number to dots or chart's areas as I ploted in the regression diagnostics charts ( blue lines shapes) ?:

```
df <- read.table(text = "userid target birds    wolfs     
                222       1        9         7 
                444       1        8         4 
                234       0        2         8 
                543       1        2         3 
                678       1        8         3 
                987       0        1         2 
                294       1        7         16 
                608       0        1         5 
                123       1        17        7 
                321       1        8         7 
                226       0        2         7 
                556       0        20        3 
                334       1        6         3 
                225       0        1         1 
                999       0        3         11 
                987       0        30         1  ",header = TRUE)
lm<-lm(target~birds+wolfs,data=df)
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(lm)
```

[image]

Comment: take a look at `?plot.lm`

Comment: `ggplot2::fortify(lm)` Plot it again with ggplot2, add the labels with `annotate` or `geom_text` or simply look at the table and find the values you need.

Comment: Hello @jeremycg , I guess you mean using the id.n attribute , for example : plot(lm,id.n = 8).But I wonder it there away to display a row number for specific point or points in an area (like using sort of coordinates)

Comment: for that amount of detail, you would probably be better off using the ggplot2 method, or replotting yourself

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at ggplot2::fortify(lm) as @Vlo suggested.